# Seam - list all components

Tags: java, seam

I would like to get a list of all the components so that I can further process them.  Is this possible, if so, how can I do that?  I don't believe I can observe all postCreate events since it is simply an exact match and not a regular expression.

@Observer("org.jboss.seam.postCreate.")

You can only observe those events and not * as it is put into a map where the key is a string.

Any ideas?

Walter

Comment: I think you've got this the wrong way around. What sort of processing do you want to do? Maybe there's a more DI friendly way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said

> I would like to get a list of all the components

**For each class declared as a component**, Seam creates a component definition and
stashes it away **in the application scope**. Its naming convention follows The pattern

- <COMPONENT_NAME>.component

So you can use

```
/**
  * Metamodel class for component classes
  *
  * Similar to org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition used by Spring
  */ 
org.jboss.seam.Component

Context context = Contexts.getApplicationContext();
for (String name: context.getNames()) {
    Object object = context.get(name);
    if(object instanceof org.jboss.seam.Component) {
        Component component = (Component) object;

        System.out.println(component.getName());
        System.out.println(component.getType());
        System.out.println(component.getScope());
        System.out.println(component.getTimeout());
        System.out.println(component.isStartup());
        System.out.println(component.isSynchronize());
    }
}
```

If you want to retrieve a desired component, you can use

```
Object object = Component.getInstance(component.getName());
```

Comment: Thanks - I didn't see that in the API, that looks like exactly what I need.